# Inserting a data which should not be less than current date validation

Tags: java, regex

When I insert a new data in the database, it should not be less than the current date to be validated. How do I find the correct RegEx for that?

```
@FutureOrPresent
@Pattern(message = "Invalid date", regexp = "?")
private Date dataInserted;
```

Comment: That is not something you can solve with a regex.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: If not with a regex can be solved, than how do I do that?

Comment: @ioio79 shouldn't the `@FutureOrPresent` annotation take care of that? How on earth did you think you could use regexes for it, or did you just copy this code from somewhere?

Comment: I found that annotation in Intellij and even if I use it I can still update the rows with dates less than current date, so it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your problem correctly, but why don't you use a constraint in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can introduce a new annotation in PresentOrFuture.java:

```
    @Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = PresentOrFutureValidator.class)
    @Documented
    public @interface PresentOrFuture {
        String message() default "{PresentOrFuture.message}";
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    }
```

Then you have to define the validator in PresentOrFutureValidator.java:

```
    public class PresentOrFutureValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<PresentOrFuture, Date> {

        public final void initialize(final PresentOrFuture annotation) {}

        public final boolean isValid(final Date value,
            final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

            // Only use the date for comparison
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            Date today = calendar.getTime();

            // Your date must be after today or today (== not before today)
            return !value.before(today) || value.after(today);

        }
    }
```

Then you have to set:

```
    @NotNull
    @PresentOrFuture
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;
```